# How to create new column using unicode text from from another column in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas data frame containing some unicodes and I want to create new column with `dog`, `cat` or `None`.

Here is my dataframe:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'comment': ['Alice likes ', 'Bob likes ', 'Harry likes dog', 'Don likes cat!', 'this is a tree']})
```

How to create a new column like this?

```
           comment label
0    Alice likes    dog
1      Bob likes    dog
2  Harry likes dog   dog
3   Don likes cat!   cat
4   this is a tree  None
```

Note: I have few emojis of cats and dogs, and I can manually construct a dictionary.

```py
dict_dog = {'dog': ['dog', "", ""]}
dict_cat = {'cat': ['cat']
```

Then I struggle with how to proceed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create your `dict` like

```
dog = dict.fromkeys(['dog', "", ""],'dog')

cat= dict.fromkeys(['cat'],'cat')
```

Then we using the same logic like before `str.findall`

```
d = {**dog ,**cat}
df.comment.str.findall('|'.join(d.keys())).str[0].map(d)
```

Comment: AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'd'

Comment: @MilkyWay007 did you try `d = {**dog ,**cat}`

Comment: df.comment.str.findall('|'.d.keys()).str[0].map(d)   This line gives error.

Comment: @MilkyWay007 my mistake  change to `df.comment.str.findall('|'.join(d.keys())).str[0].map(d)
`

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
df['label']= np.where( df['comment'].str.contains('(dog| |)'), 'dog','cat')
```

You can do nested `np.where` if there are more animals than just the 2. Like below.

```
df['label']= (np.where( df['comment'].str.contains('(dog| |)'),'dog', 
                   (np.where(df['comment'].str.contains('cat'), 'cat','None'))))
```

Answer (score 1):

This is another way by using **Regex** and **Apply()**

```
import re

decoder = {'dog': ['dog', "", ""], 'cat': ['cat']}

def check(c):
    c = list(map(lambda l: re.sub('[!@#$]', '', l), c.split(' ')))
    res_dog = [i for i in c if i in decoder['dog']]
    res_cat = [i for i in c if i in decoder['cat']]
    return 'dog' if res_dog else 'cat' if res_cat else None

# Apply function
df['label'] = df['comment'].apply(check)
```

Result:

```
         comment    label
0   Alice likes   dog
1   Bob likes     dog
2   Harry likes dog dog
3   Don likes cat!  cat
4   this is a tree  None
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for both capital and small letters. 
This is the recommended way of creating column in pandas. If simpler things works, then try them, then only leap for the complex ones.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'comment': ['Alice likes ', 'Bob likes ', 'Harry likes dog', 'Don likes cat!', 'this is a tree']})


df['comment'] = df['comment'].astype(str)
df['label'] = 'None'

df.loc[df.comment.str.lower().str.contains("dog"),'label'] = 'dog'
df.loc[df.comment.str.lower().str.contains("cat"),'label'] = 'dog'

df.loc[df.comment.str.contains(""),'label'] = 'dog'
df.loc[df.comment.str.contains(""),'label'] = 'dog'

print(df)

           comment label
0    Alice likes    dog
1      Bob likes    dog
2  Harry likes dog   dog
3   Don likes cat!   dog
4   this is a tree  None
```